# Data wrote using FileOutputStream disappear after restarting program

Tags: java, io

I'm learning java and I have made simple program that simply reads value from JTextField and saves it to file using FileOutputStream.
My question is: is it normal for data to be unreadable (using same program with FileInputStream) after restarting it? If i read it without terminating program it works fine.
How can I make data wrote to file permament?
Edit:
It seems the file is being cleaned when starting the program.
Here is the code:

```
public class Test extends JFrame
{
JTextField field;
JButton write;
JButton read;
File file;
FileOutputStream fOut;
FileInputStream fIn;
int x;

Test() throws IOException
{
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    field = new JTextField(4);
    write = new JButton("Write");
    read = new JButton("Read");
    file = new File("save.txt");
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    add(field);
    add(write, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    add(read, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(160,60);
    write.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            x = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            try
            {
                fOut.write(x);
                System.out.println("Saving completed.");
                fOut.flush();
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                System.out.println("Saving failed.");
            }

        }
    });
    read.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            try
            {
                x = fIn.read();
                fIn.close();
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                System.out.println("Reading failed.");
            }
        }
    });
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    new Test();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you opened the file and see any data there? Data should be there, it shouldn't remove on restart. Without code it is hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: fOut = new FileOutputStream(file); becomes  fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);` will overwrite the file, you need to use `fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);` to append to it.

Comment: Then how should I make this if i want there to be only one value in the file? I don't want them to stack.

Comment: Open, read and close the file with the `FileInputStream` and then reopen it with the `FileOutputStream` (without appending). You could also only open it for writing when you actually do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you `flush()` and `close()` the streams.

Comment: @Jon Skeet But not flushing before closing can result in some messed up error handling (with some decorators, under certain conditions).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: In terms of if there's already an IOException, but you then try to close which in turn forces a flush, or something else?

Comment: @Jon Skeet JDK code like this: `
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
          flush();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }`

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: Ick, I wasn't aware of that. Nasty.

Comment: @Jon Skeet It's all a mess with this flushing in close. The flush will get repeated in (probably) every close down the chain. Execute Around and be done with it once.

Answer (score 0):

here's some code to open a file for writing .. observe the "true" parameter which means we APPEND the text at the end instead of adding it to the start. The same goes for FileOutputStream .. if you don't specify the second argument (true) you will end up with an overwritten file.

```
try{
  // Create file 
  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt",true);
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
  out.write("Hello Java");
  //Close the output stream
  out.close();
  }catch (IOException e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: Note that catching Exception isn't generally a good idea, and `close()` should usually be in a finally block. Oh, and this will use the platform default encoding, which is usually a bad idea too.